# pyopengl change brightness of textures

Tags: python, opengl, textures, pyopengl

I have a program where I render two textures that are bound to some polys and add the results using this:

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_ADD)
```

This works well and fast but I would like a way to change the brightness of each texture before adding them, like a gain value. This value needs to change at runtime so I can't just bake my brightness into my texture.

Also the nature of my program means I won't know how many textures I will be blending until runtime so I need a solution that will work with n textures.

Does anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use fragment shaders, you should write code in the fragment shader that changes the brightness with a shader parameter that your application passes in. This approach will be both fast and flexible.

Comment: Is is possible to have an arbitrary number of textures in a fragment shader, I ask because I don't know how many textures I want to mix until runtime, jt

Comment: Also I definatley 'could' use fragment shaders, I have no restrictions, I just don't know how to yet :)

Comment: There are two approaches to rendering multiple textures on surfaces using OpenGL
1. Multi-pass - render the object multiple times, with different textures. This is easy but less performant. This also doesn't depend on hardware capabilities. Use this when option 2 limits you.
2. Multi-texturing - Depends on how many texture units your hardware can simultaneously support. This is fast and most hardware supports 8+ textures at a time.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you get started? http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/shader_1.xhtml